# Why isn't the value of the object properties inserted here?

Tags: vue.js

I started learning vue yesterday and I'm now fiddling around on the CLI3. 
Currently I'm trying out the different approaches to inserting data into my markup.

Here, I basically want to make a "list of Lists". 
This here is list1:

```
<template>
<div>
<ul v-for="item in items">
  <li :text="item"></li>
</ul>
</div>

</template>

<script>
 export default{
   name:"list1",
   data() {
     return {
       items: {
         item1 : "itemA",
         item2 : "itemB",
         item3 : "itemC"
       }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

This is the list of lists:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>All my stuff in a biiig list!</h1>
  <listOfLists />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import listOfLists from '@/components/listOfLists.vue'

export default {
  name: 'myComplexView.vue',
  components: {
    listOfLists
  }
}
```

And this is inserted into myComplexView.vue inside views (im working with routing as well, though it doesnt work perfectly yet as you will see on the screenshot), which you can see here:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>All my stuff in a biiig list!</h1>
  <listOfLists />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import listOfLists from '@/components/listOfLists.vue'

export default {
  name: 'myComplexView.vue',
  components: {
    listOfLists
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the result Im getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/llw0A.jpg
Since routing doesnt work correctly yet, I had to enter the url into the browser manually. Fortunately, the site at least loaded that way as well, so I can tackle these problems bit by bit ^^

As you can see, the data was iterated over correctly by the v-for. 
However, the data wasn't inserted in the text attribute of the li elements. 
I'm a bit clueless about the cause though.
Maybe I'm not binding to the correct attribute? Vue is using its own naming conventions, based off standard html and jquery as far as I understood.

Comment: You seem to have posted the same code twice. Code you update the question to contain the real code for `listOfLists.vue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this in your template:

```html
<li :text="item"></li>
```

This will bind the `text` attribute to the value, outputting, e.g.:

```html
<li text="itemA"></li>
```

You should be able to see this in the developer tools. In the picture you posted you hadn't expanded the relevant elements so the attributes can't be seen.

I assume what you want is to set the content. For that you'd either use `v-text`:

```html
<li v-text="item"></li>
```

or more likely:

```html
<li>{{ item }}</li>
```

Either of these will output:

```html
<li>itemA</li>
```

On an unrelated note, I would add that this line will create multiple lists:

```html
<ul v-for="item in items">
```

It's unclear if that's what you want. You're going to create 3 `<ul>` elements, each with a single `<li>` child. If you want to create a single `<ul>` then move the `v-for` onto the `<li>`.

Comment: Awesome, you totally read my mind and solved my problem perfectly! Big thanks! :D